# Efficient  way of sending data to web service 

Tags: android, ksoap2, gprs

I have web Service on .net . And i use to upload data to this web service at regular interval of time . My data contains mostly string and some byte[] of Image (Around 8 of them). It takes around 4-5 mins to upload .

Now my problem is while sending data via GPRS (Android Mobile ) and it take lot of time to upload data (sometime connection time out also occurs), Can any one tell me how to improve upload time .

I am using KSOAP2 for sending data .

Comment: Just Go through this link http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data may be it will be helpful for you...

Comment: so you have your web service hosted on a real server and you are now trying to access that webservice from your android phone using gprs right? can u tell me the speed your getting while uploading?

Comment: @Parth_90 : Yes , ur right . Sorry i dnt knw the upload speed . My data contains around 8 pics .

Comment: @Parth_90 : How to check Speed of my GPRS and how to improve it .

Comment: It depends upon the network provider. I get around 155-200 kbps using Vodafone and Airtel.

Comment: @Parth_90 : m using airtel .Any suggestions ?

Comment: Yes Airtel is good. Since your are sending/uploading pictures I suggest you choose some good GPRS plan that fits your requirements. Also, I wanted to mention that I have an Android app that connects a remote database via web service(.NET .asmx). Can u tell how you hosted your webservices? I could then try myself and answer your question coz I haven't tried hosting on real server. I am working at present on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

There are some possible techniques for reducing the data to be transfered - however all of them require special server features or if not supported changes on server side:

The simplest way would be to use [HTTP transport compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) but that is a feature that has to be supported by the server.

An alternative that reduces the XML overhead would be to switch to WBXML (binary encoded xml - once developed for "[WAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Application_Protocol)") but AFAIK KSoap does not support it (and most web-service servers, too)

Comment: I have checked my server it support HTTP transport compression is enabled by default . Any other suggestion u have ?

Comment: Then the only I answer I have for you is simple: Don't use SOAP! Encapsulating binary data in XML is generally a bad idea. Just pack your images into HTTP POST requests and upload them to a simple Servlet on the server. Images like JPEG and PNG files are already well compressed therefore no additional effort is needed.